# How to match two dataframes based on lookup fields and update those fields only in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes. I have to match them based on lookup field columns and update those columns in one of the dataframe if found any mismatch.

Example:

```
lkp_field = ['program_name', 'file_type']

df1:

project_number      file_name      program_name      file_type  
10                  pdf_11         plasma protein    feedback

df2:

project_number      file_name      program_name      file_type  
10                  pdf_13         oncology          guidence
```

In above example we can see df1 & df2 are not matching so I have to update Lkp_field in df2 from df1.

Final Output would be:

```
df2:

project_number      file_name      program_name      file_type  
10                  pdf_13         plasma protein    feedback
```

Comment: `df2.update(df1)`

Comment: @AnuragDabas - It update all columns, OP need update only `lkp_field`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need match by `project_number` values first match DataFrame by convert values to index and then use [`DataFrame.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) only by selected columns:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('project_number')
df2 = df2.set_index('project_number')
df2.loc[:, lkp_field].update(df1.loc[:, lkp_field])
```

If same index of both DataFrames:

```
df2.loc[:, lkp_field].update(df1.loc[:, lkp_field])
```

Comment: will it work if df1 & df2 have more than 100 records?

Comment: @ShivikaPatel - Sure, there is no reason why not working.